# React Child Component componentDidMount not fired

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am currently using [ant design tabs](https://ant.design/components/tabs/) to control the tabs and within each tab I inserted a custom component within the `TabPane`. But the child custom component works quite unexpected. Before I clicked the tab title, the child component will not load (the `constructor` and `componentDidMount` will not be fired), BUT I want to load some data once the child component `mounted` to the tab instead of being shown.

Why it happened? ~~Ant Design~~ for performance concern?

Currently I am moving the data loading to the parent and handle them there. But still quite curious about the `loading` issue caused by `ant design`.

Comment: Why do you want to be loaded when components are not visible? If you want to deal with that data, you need to load it in parent, and give to children as props.

Comment: Actually I want the data collected once the `tabs` created and when the user checks it, the data will be there (collected since the `tabs` created) and meantime trying to let the parent clean enough (there are lots of things already for the parent). Now I am using the parent to handle the data collection but I feel like it's kind of messy.

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide your code to illustrate your problem. It is also easier for people to answer your question.